# Метод заполнения fill выдает ошибку, что не так делаю?

Tags: laravel

Вот такую ошибку выдает:

> Add [_method] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\BlogCategory].

Вот весь код файла:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Blog\Admin;

use App\Models\BlogCategory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class CategoryController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $paginator = BlogCategory::paginate(15);

        return view('blog.admin.categories.index', compact('paginator'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
     dd(__METHOD__);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         dd(__METHOD__);
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
       $item = BlogCategory::findOrFail($id);
       $categoryList = BlogCategory::all();

        return view('blog.admin.categories.edit', compact('item', 'categoryList'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $item = BlogCategory::find($id);
         if(empty($item)) {
            return back()
            ->withErrors(['msg' => "Запись id=[{$id}] не найдена"])
            ->withInput();
        }

        $data = $request->all();
        $result = $item->fill($data)->save();


        if($result) {
            return redirect()
            ->route('blog.admin.categories.edit', $item->id)
            ->with(['success' => "Успешно сохранено"]);
        }else{
            return back()
            ->withErrors(['msg' => 'Ошибка сохранения'])
            ->withInput();
        }


    }
}
```

Именно после этой строчки у меня ошибка:

```
    $result = $item->fill($data)->save();
```

Не знаю что уже и делать, документацию читал официальную и гуглил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1** Предпочтительный вариант. При использовании методов `fill()` и др., необходимо определить поля, которым разрешено массовое присвоение:

```php
class BlogCategory extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'user_ip',
    'content',
  ];
}
```

**2** Либо определить поля, которым **не** разрешено массовое присвоение значений:

```php
class BlogCategory extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [
    '_method',
    '_token'
  ];
}
```

**3** Либо определять "на лету", какие поля необходимо исключить/оставить для создания/обновления модели:

```
// Исключаем поля `_method` и `_token`.
$data = $request->except(['_method', '_token']);

// Либо оставляем поля `name` и `content`.
$data = $request->only(['name', 'content']);
```

---

**Откуда берутся эти поля?**

Из формы:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT') <!-- это будущее поле `_method` -->
    @csrf <!-- это будущее поле `_token` -->
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Документация [Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) в разделе "Mass Assignment" (к сожалению нет якоря к разделу) говорит о том, что:

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Для Вашего случая:

> If you already have a model instance, you may use the fill method to populate it with an array of attributes

Проще говоря - Вам нужно в модель `BlogCategory` (ведь `$item instanceof BlogCategory` ?) добавить в `protected $fillable = [...]` необходимые поля, которые будут заполнятся при Mass Assignment.

Т.е. судя по ошибке:

```
class BlogCategory extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        '_method',
    ];

    // other code ...
}
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов вопрос был в том, как исправить ошибку, я не строил предположений, что автору нужно в БД, а что нет

Comment: @РустамГимранов и если роут не определен, то ловим ошибку?

Comment: @РустамГимранов  Спасибо за ответ, пытался добавить в код вашу строчку в файла, который скопирован выше в вопросе моем,  `$data = $request->except('_method')` но все равно выдаёт ошибку, только вот такую :` Add [_token] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\BlogCategory].`

Comment: @Остин ну так сделайте тоже самое с `_token`, если он Вам не нужен, или добавьте его в `$fillable`