# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel

Не могу добавить пользователя в базу Laravel.

**Шаблон**:

```
<form class="col-12" method="post" action="{{ route('users.store') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create user</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Контроллер**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  dd(\DB::table('users')->insert(request()->input()));
}
```

**Миграции**:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('email')->unique();
  $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->string('role');
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Скриншот ошибки**:

[image: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into <code>users</code> (<code>_token</code>, <code>name</code>, <code>email</code>, <code>password</code>) values (mXjaGI8T9Frau3NoYS73Oo3mcjrpcSd99LJqPCUM, Светлана Троян, svtrojan16@gmail.com, xx))]

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/996703/256824

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = request()->except(['_token']);
DB::table('users')->insert($data));
```

Comment: скорее уж `User::create(request()->except(['_token']));` Не канонично обходить модели  стороной :^

Comment: Ответ был дан в том стиле в котором был задан вопрос, автор использует `query builder` таков же и ответ. Возможно автор даже не пользуется моделями.

Comment: Судя по вопросам, автор вообще не пользуется документацией от фреймворка. Вряд-ли он вообще знает что за модели и с чем их едят.

Comment: Я только изучаю . И очень благодарна за ваши ответы. Ошибка ушла но юзер в базу не добавился $data = request()->except(['_token','name','email','password']);
        \DB::table('users')->insert($data);
 
        return redirect()->route('users.index');Подскажите как правильно сделать

Comment: @svtrojan так а зачем вы исключили все данные?

Comment: скиньте пжл ссылку что почитать как правильно сделать?

Comment: $data = request()->except(['_token']);

        \DB::table('users')->insert($data);

        dd(\DB::table('users')->insert(request()->toArray()));

        return redirect()->route('users.show'); Сейчас пишет что надо добавить юзеру роль по умолчанию . запуталась совсем(

Comment: @svtrojan https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch Бесплатный курс по основам ларавел, посмотрите его, будет проще